# Fullcalendar - event on prev/next click and get value

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How would it be possible to call a function by clicking on the prev/next button in monthly view and how to access the value (for example: 2016-04) in that function? I would like to manipulate the URL with the current monthly view by clicking next/prev button.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Each time you change to another month view with prev/next button, a viewRender event is triggered, so you can add to your calendar config a callback to that event. The view parameter has moment dates to first day and last day rendered(start/end, usually they are from previous/next month), and first and last day of current view (intervalStart/intervalEnd, where you can get current month) .

Also, you can got the current date with .fullCalendar('getDate'):

```
[...]
viewRender: function(view, element) {
    console.log(view.start,view.end, view.intervalStart, view.intervalEnd);
    console.log($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'));
}
[...]
```

Documentation: [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/), [getDate](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/).

Comment: If viewRender is used, dayRender is not getting called for the first time calendar load. it will become a problem if i use some validations( showing day colors) in dayRender callback

Comment: I am not using currently fullCalendar and I can not test it, but you can try to do same validations also in viewRender event for first time, and leave it in dayRender for following renders.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the question directly, but what I needed was to run a function when previous, next, or the view changed. (I needed to compute the total number of hours of an event type) There is a callback method called "datesRender", which is triggered whenever the dates been rendered change. Checkout [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-api)